# InstallShield limited edition with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using `InstallShield` limited edition with `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate`. Everything was working fine till my laptop got crashed and I have put my hard drive in a new laptop. Now I am getting an error: `The product license has been corrupted. You must repair the license before you can continue. Click yes to repair now.`

Now, I tried repairing but same message appears again. I uninstalled VS2013 and then re-installed still same message, I also downloaded a fresh copy with new registration number still same message. I am really annoyed so please let me know a work around for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

OK this is over a year ago but for anyone Googling this!

I had the same issue in both VS 2012 & VS2015; InstallShield Limited Edition (tried the 2012 & 2015 versions of it).

Same thing - replaced a HD (needed more space).  Restored PC from a backup; ran VS & InstallShield LE didn't work - tried to reactivate itself online & failed; and gave me an offline (manual) request to paste & send to InstallShield support (which I did - note - it doesn't put the whole request in the auto-email; so have to manually copy/paste the request contents into the email!).  They responded quickly with a "response" key (looks like an automated email).  All looked good but every (subsequent) time I started VS & tried a new InstallShield project it didn't offer me the "enter response" box I was expecting - did that "need to repair" bit you mention and failed.

So I contacted InstallShield support and they gave this solution which works:

**Solution:**
Ensure InstallShield is closed then open regedit and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\InstallShield[VersionNumber]
Update the value of the OfflineTransactionPending key to '1'.

Then (re)start VS and do a new InstallShield project; and bingo up popped the box where I could enter the manual (offline) activation key; and all good.

Answer (score 1):

Used the solution proposed by Michael. Works, but in my case after I added the offline activation key still no success.

Then used tsconfig.exe /info (in folder c:\program files (x86)\Install shield version \system) to check if license key was ok. It was not. After using tsconfig.exe/activate license key was valid (check it with tsconfig.exe /info).